# nonlinear optimizaion in R

Tags: r, wolfram-mathematica, precision, nonlinear-optimization

I tried to minimize the following function:

```
func <- function(qq){
  x <- qq[1]
  y <- qq[2]
  output <- 1 - 2 * x + x^2 - 2 * y + 2 * x * y + y^2
  return(output)
}
```

when x+y=1 and 0<=x,y<=1. To use gosolnp in Rsolnp package, firstly, I defined cons to use it in eqfun argument:

```
cons <- function(qq)
  sum(qq)
```

Then I applied gosolnp function:

```
install.packages("Rsolnp")
require(Rsolnp)
gosolnp(fun = func, LB = c(0, 0), UB = c(1, 1), eqfun = cons, eqB = 1)

res$pars
[1] 0.8028775 0.1971225
res$value
[1]  2.606528e-09 -5.551115e-17
```

the answer should be x = 0 and y = 1, but as you can try in every run of gosolnp you will get new points which func is approximately 0 at that points (and not exactly).
 Mathematica and Maple do optimization for this function very fast and give the true answer which is x = 0 and y = 1, but instead every run in R gives a new solution which is not correct.

I also tried another optimization function as spg() in alabama or DEoptim, but the problem remained unsolved.

So my question are:

1- is there any solution that I can minimize func in R?

2- is there any difference between precision in R and Mathematica and why Mathematica could give me the exact answer but R not?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two variables `x` and `y`, with `y = 1 - x`, then you really have a problem in just one variable `x`. Noting that, you can reparametrise your function to be

```
1 - 2 * x + x^2 - 2 * (1 - x) + 2 * x * (1 - x) + (1 - x)^2
```

and going through the algebra shows that this is constant as a function of `x`. Thus *any* value of `x` in (0, 1) is a solution, and which one your algorithm converges to will basically be random: based on numerical roundoff and your choice of starting point.

The fact that `gosolnp`'s returned value is zero to within the limits of numerical precision should have been a tipoff, or even just plotting the curve.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to these particular packages, but `nloptr(...)` in package `nloptr` seems to work well:

```
# Non-Linear Optimization (package::nloptr)
F <- function(v){  
  x=v[1]
  y=v[2]
  output <- 1 - 2 * x + x^2 - 2 * y + 2 * x * y + y^2
}
Hc <- function(v) return(1-sum(v))

library(nloptr)
opt <- nloptr(x0=c(1/2,1/2), eval_f=F, lb = c(0,0), ub = c(1,1), 
              eval_g_eq = Hc, 
              opts = list(algorithm="NLOPT_GN_ISRES",maxeval=1e6))
opt$solution
# [1] 0.0005506997 0.9994492982
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is identically equal to 0 so there is no point in trying to minimize it.

```
library(Ryacas)
x <- Sym("x")
y <- 1-x
Simplify( 1 - 2 * x + x^2 - 2 * y + 2 * x * y + y^2)
```

which gives:

```
expression(0)
```